# NuGet package browsing: How to see packages ordered by download count (descending)

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

**Context**

I often use NuGet package UI in VS 2017, and filtering for a keyword, for example 'Benchmark'. Then my next move would be to sort descending the result list by download count, but it is unfortunately not possible. (it would be a great productivity tool)

**Question**

What is the most seamless way to find an pick a package quickly picking one of the most downloaded, then add to my solution or project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I keep this little PowerShell script on my desktop.  It won't add anything to your project, but it's a pretty quick way to search and sort by downloads.

```bsh
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
    [string]
    $query
)

$RawPkgs = Find-Package $query -ProviderName NuGet -Source nuget.org
Write-Output "Found $($RawPkgs.Count) results"
$PkgList = @()

foreach($pkg in $RawPkgs) {
    $data = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Name = $pkg.Name
        Summary = $pkg.Summary
        Downloads = [int]$pkg.Meta.Attributes['downloadCount']
    }
    $PkgList += $data
}

$PkgList | Sort-Object { $_.Downloads } -Descending | Format-Table Name, Downloads, Summary -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the most seamless way to find an pick a package quickly picking one of the most downloaded, then add to my solution or project?

At this moment, I am afraid there is no such way to find nuget package sort by most downloaded count.

According to the document [Finding and evaluating NuGet packages for your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/finding-and-choosing-packages#search-syntax):

> When you visit nuget.org or open the Package Manager UI in Visual
>   Studio, you see **a list of packages sorted by total downloads**. This
>   immediately shows you the most widely-used packages across the
>   millions of .NET projects.
>
> For specific needs, searching by tags (within the Visual Studio
>   Package Manager or on a portal like nuget.org) is the most common
>   means of discovering a suitable package.
>
> At this time, **search results are sorted only by relevance**.

So, when we search one nuget package via Package Manager UI, the search results are sorted only by **relevance**. This is design by NuGet.

Besides, many other community members submit a user voice to Visual Studio team to [Manage Nuget Packages default sort order](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/8557207-manage-nuget-packages-default-sort-order). You vote and add your comments for this voice, When there are enough communities vote and add comments for this feedback, the product team member will take this feedback seriously.

Hope this help.

Comment: I think the community should not begging for this feature. This is so basic, every UX designer should aware of this...

Comment: The link to User Voice is dead. Also I still cannot sort package by download in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 1):

If you conduct your search on the nuget.org website, they now provide a filter to sort by downloads.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).